# Installing JupyterHub helm on EKS cluster: Additional property namespace is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, jupyterhub

I am following https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/latest/jupyterhub/installation.html to install Jupyterhub on my EKS cluster using CICD.
This repo is working fine for other deployments.

I have just downloaded helm charts and all the files from https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/ and moved to my repo.
Just updated the secret in values.yaml, other than that everything is kept same.
After pushing my changes I am getting error in Jenkins logs as-

```
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release jupyterhub
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /mnt/apps
    
Release "jupyterhub" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the
following chart(s): jupyterhub:- (root): Additional property namespace is not allowed
```

I have validated the values.yaml by converting yaml to json and its valid.
Command which is running to install helm is -

> docker run -i -v
> /devops/jenkins-agent-home/workspace/mnt/apps
> -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 -e AWS_ACCOUNT=********** -e
> ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=********** -e ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=****
> ********.com/asy/-aws-tools/develop/aws-cli /bin/bash -c
> 'aws eks update-kubeconfig --name *****-us-e1 --region us-east-1;
> helm history jupyterhub --max 20 --namespace ****-platform-ns; helm
> lint . --namespace ****-platform-ns --with-subcharts; helm upgrade
> --install jupyterhub . -f ./values.yaml --set namespace=******-platform-ns  --namespace ****-platform-ns --debug
> --atomic --wait --timeout 10m

converted some values to *

Has someone face this issue?